# How to add no of days as well as month to specific date?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, date, addition

I have a date like 31 May, 2017. With this date I need to add 2 more days.
Then another requirement, for the same date I need to add 18 months.
I tried the following code .

```
var rootDate = 31 May,2017;
var firstDate = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(); 

var tempdate = firstDate.setDate(rootDate.getDate() +2);
firstDate = $filter('date')(tempdate , "dd MMM, yyyy");

var tempDateTwo = lastDate.setDate(rootDate.getMonth() +18);
secondDate =  $filter('date')(tempDateTwo , "dd MMM, yyyy");
```

It's giving me Error 'Invalid Date'. what's wrong in the code?

Comment: change `var rootDate = new Date("31 May,2017")`

Comment: If you want to work with date, I suggest you take a look at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @sachila Thanks for that..It's working for adding 2 days and not working for adding 18 months..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, convert the date to a Date object

`var rootDate = new Date("31 May,2017");`

and to set month use `setMonth` method

`lastDate.setMonth(rootDate.getMonth() +18);`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$filter){
var rootDate = new Date("31 May,2017");
var firstDate = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(); 

var tempdate = firstDate.setDate(rootDate.getDate() +2);
firstDate = $filter('date')(tempdate , "dd MMM, yyyy");
console.log(firstDate)

var tempDateTwo = lastDate.setMonth(rootDate.getMonth() +18);
lastDate =  $filter('date')(tempDateTwo , "dd MMM, yyyy");
console.log(lastDate)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
1:For adding days `moment().add(2,'days').format('DD MMMM, YYYY');`. 
2:For adding month `moment().add(18,'months').format('DD MMMM, YYYY');;`

Answer (score 0):

I have revised your code to work this way, # will bring in what you wanted to achieve.

```
    var rootDate = '31 May,2017';
    var firstDate = new Date(rootDate);
    var lastDate = new Date(rootDate);

    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + parseInt(2));      

    lastDate.setMonth(lastDate.getMonth() + parseInt(18));
```